# vmouseout vmouseover event not fired

Tags: jquery, css, mouseevent

I have two elements listening to `mouseover`event, when the even triggers the handler will append a `tooltip` on the `position` of `e.clientY`and `e.clientX`

These two elements also listen to `mouseout` event, when the even triggers the handler will `remove()`the `tooltip` element.

It works perfect on laptop screen, but I also want these effects work in touchscreens.So I make these two events also listening to `vmouseover`and `vmouseout`.
But it does not seem to work. The the `vmouseout` event wont fire on touchscreen.

That is the syntax I use:

```
$( ".selector" ).on("mouseover vmousever", function( event ) { //append tooltip} )
$( ".selector" ).on( "mouseout vmouseout", function( event ) { //remove tooltip} )
```

This is the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/59rnyt37/1/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Did not link to a jQuery mobile library.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```